# Conditionally wrap a directive with another, based on scope attribute

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I would like to know if it's possible to have the following

```
<my-directive wrap=true></my-directive>
<h5>A header </h5>
<p>lorem ipsum text</p>
```

to generate something like this when wrap is set to true:

```
<conditional-wrapper>
    <my-directive></my-directive>
    <h5>A header </h5>
    <p>lorem ipsum text</p>
<conditional-wrapper>
```

Edit: Note that when the wrap attribute is set to true, i want the `<conditional-wrapper>` directive to wrap everything there is on my template, not just `<my-directive>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can achieve that by providing a compile function, like so:

```
app.directive( 'myDirective', function () {
  return {
    restrict : 'E',

    compile : function ( tElement, tAttrs ) {
      var parent = tElement.parent();

      if ( tAttrs.wrap && !/^conditional-wrapper$/i.test( parent[0].nodeName ) ) {
        var html = tElement.parent().html();

        var wrapper = angular.element( '<conditional-wrapper>' );
        parent.empty().append( wrapper );
        wrapper.html( html );
      }

      return function link() {}
    }
  }
})
```

check out the POC [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/cn5SCEvEKAnBFptuBYZw?p=preview) and let me know if that's what you're after.

Comment: if you want to wrap ONLY the directive AND it's following siblings, you would need to modify the script a bit, but it's still quite easy to do

Comment: Ideally I would like the <conditional-wrapper> to wrap around all html elements on the template (or body in this plunkr) http://plnkr.co/edit/6kdf44NowhKpjd4qbeX0?p=preview (the other list item, spans, h5, p etc.. should all be within the blue border)

Comment: then modify the function so it doesn't refer to `tElement.parent()`, but `document.body` or so :-)

Comment: Don't have access to jqlite methods for document.body
http://plnkr.co/edit/WPrXx0a7eG0egy7ksDpz?p=preview

Comment: was about to comment that you need to wrap it :-)

Comment: as an alternative, you could use `multiElement` property for directive definition to know EXACTLY what content should be wrapped

Comment: Needed to angular.element(document.body) to wrap body with jqlite methods. It works fine now! http://plnkr.co/edit/k7fYpZMvUzRv20SzqQBb?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Use `ng-if`

```
<div ng-if="wrap">
  <conditional-wrapper>
    <my-directive></my-directive>
    <h5>A header </h5>
    <p>lorem ipsum text</p>
  <conditional-wrapper>
</div>
<div ng-if="!wrap">
  <my-directive></my-directive>
  <h5>A header </h5>
  <p>lorem ipsum text</p>
</div>
```

You may want to wrap

```
<my-directive></my-directive>
<h5>A header </h5>
<p>lorem ipsum text</p>
```

in a directive to make your html cleaner.

Comment: I've tried to oversimplify my problem, so I forgot to mention something crucial. There will be sibling elements of <my-directive>, and in case the wrap attribute is set to true, these would need to be transcluded to the <conditional-wrapper> directive...
It's a bit trickier than an ng-if, but thank you!

Comment: @IgnorantUser I'm not clear on what you are saying there. Can you please update your question with the full details and examples.

Comment: I edited the original description. Hopefully it makes more sense now?

Comment: @IgnorantUser `ng-if` still works just fine. Just add the same code to both conditions. You may want to just wrap `<my-directive></my-directive><h5>A header </h5><p>lorem ipsum text</p>` in another directive.

Comment: Those HTLM elements they're not gonna be the same. This is why i can't put them in the directive template. It could be an h5, or a div, or a span or you name it

Comment: @IgnorantUser Then create a directive where you pass in the "extra html", perhaps as a templateurl.

Comment: could you provide any examples?

Comment: @IgnorantUser Probably your best bet would be [transclusion](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-a-directive-that-wraps-other-elements)